# Unable to get the Font-Family as required

Tags: css, fonts

I have my font-family in the following order. It works fine in one server but in another server its reading the second font-family(verdana) instead of the first(breuer-text-medium). I have the fonts installed correctly in their locations but not sure what is missing. Can some one please help me.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "breuer_textmedium";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: url("fonts/breuertext-medium-webfont.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("fonts/breuertext-medium-webfont.woff") format("woff"), url("fonts/breuertext-medium-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"), url("fonts/breuertext-medium-webfont.svg#breuer_textmedium") format("svg");
}
```

Comment: This is my font-family order - font-family: "breuer_textmedium",verdana,arial;

Comment: Have you verified (in your browser development tools: network tab, or in the server logfiles) that the font file is loaded by the browser?

Comment: Yes the fonts are loaded in the fonts tab of developer tools

Comment: try removing the underscore and replacing it with either a hyphen or space

Comment: hi, the problem was with the access to s3 server. Thanks for all your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the access privileges to s3 server.